# ParseUser.fromJSON is not a function

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I'm getting the following error message when I try to make a new user
I'm using fuse to build a mobile app but I get this error when I try to make a new user

```
ERROR: 
Name: TypeError
ErrorMessage: 'ParseUser.fromJSON' is not a function
FileName: native
LineNumber: 0
JS StackTrace: TypeError: 'ParseUser.fromJSON' is not a function
    at apply (native)
    at wrappedResolvedCallback (C:\Users\Junior McGrath\Documents\Fuse\fuse-example-video-login-screen-master\parse-1.6.7.js:5268)
    at anonymous (C:\Users\Junior McGrath\Documents\Fuse\fuse-example-video-login-screen-master\parse-1.6.7.js:5306)
    at runLater (C:\Users\Junior McGrath\Documents\Fuse\fuse-example-video-login-screen-master\parse-1.6.7.js:5301)
    at then (C:\Users\Junior McGrath\Documents\Fuse\fuse-example-video-login-screen-master\parse-1.6.7.js:5305)
    at currentUserAsync (C:\Users\Junior McGrath\Documents\Fuse\fuse-example-video-login-screen-master\parse-1.6.7.js:8078)
    at anonymous (C:\Users\Junior McGrath\Documents\Fuse\fuse-example-video-login-screen-master\parse-1.6.7.js:8491)
    at wrappedResolvedCallback (C:\Users\Junior McGrath\Documents\Fuse\fuse-example-video-login-screen-master\parse-1.6.7.js:5268)
    at anonymous (C:\Users\Junior McGrath\Documents\Fuse\fuse-example-video-login-screen-master\parse-1.6.7.js:5306)
    at runLater (C:\Users\Junior McGrath\Documents\Fuse\fuse-example-video-login-screen-master\parse-1.6.7.js:5301)
    at then (C:\Users\Junior McGrath\Documents\Fuse\fuse-example-video-login-screen-master\parse-1.6.7.js:5305)
    at request (C:\Users\Junior McGrath\Documents\Fuse\fuse-example-video-login-screen-master\parse-1.6.7.js:8485)
    at task (C:\Users\Junior McGrath\Documents\Fuse\fuse-example-video-login-screen-master\parse-1.6.7.js:4540)
    at enqueue (C:\Users\Junior McGrath\Documents\Fuse\fuse-example-video-login-screen-master\parse-1.6.7.js:8715)
    at enqueueTask (C:\Users\Junior McGrath\Documents\Fuse\fuse-example-video-login-screen-master\parse-1.6.7.js:959)
    at save (C:\Users\Junior McGrath\Documents\Fuse\fuse-example-video-login-screen-master\parse-1.6.7.js:4548)
    at anonymous (C:\Users\Junior McGrath\Documents\Fuse\fuse-example-video-login-screen-master\parse-1.6.7.js:3811)
    at wrappedResolvedCallback (C:\Users\Junior McGrath\Documents\Fuse\fuse-example-video-login-screen-master\parse-1.6.7.js:5268)
    at anonymous (C:\Users\Junior McGrath\Documents\Fuse\fuse-example-video-login-screen-master\parse-1.6.7.js:5306)
    at runLater (C:\Users\Junior McGrath\Documents\Fuse\fuse-example-video-login-screen-master\parse-1.6.7.js:5301)
    at then (C:\Users\Junior McGrath\Documents\Fuse\fuse-example-video-login-screen-master\parse-1.6.7.js:5305)
    at save (C:\Users\Junior McGrath\Documents\Fuse\fuse-example-video-login-screen-master\parse-1.6.7.js:3810)
    at signUp (C:\Users\Junior McGrath\Documents\Fuse\fuse-example-video-login-screen-master\parse-1.6.7.js:8116)
    at signUp (C:\Users\Junior McGrath\Documents\Fuse\fuse-example-video-login-screen-master\parse-1.6.7.js:7670)
    at anonymous (MainView:49)
```

I'm using the following code to call the function:

```
postuser: function() {
            var user = new Parse.User();
                user.set("username", "my name");
                user.set("password", "my pass");
                user.set("email", "email@example.com");

                // other fields can be set just like with Parse.Object
                user.set("phone", "415-555-0202");

                user.signUp(null, {
                  success: function(user) {
                    console.log("suces user")
                  },
                  error: function(user, error) {
                    // Show the error message somewhere and let the user try again.
                    console.log("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
                  }
            });
        }
    }
```

What can I do about this??